# SQL Server Linked Server To Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a linked server connection to a Postgres database, and use `openquery()` to communicate between the two.  If I create a view on sql server from the Postgres database all field types are `char` regardless of the field type on my Postgres database.

For example - this query

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(postgrez, 
                 'Select 
                  badgenumber As "badgenum"
                  ,lastunlockdate As "Last Unlock"
                  ,currentDate As "Today"
                  From doorswipesystem')
```

Has all fields as `char` on my SQL Server side - but on the Postgres side `badgenumber` is an `int`, and the two date fields are dates.  How can I in my OpenQuery keep the original data type?

**EDIT**
I tried the suggestion posted in my comments by @Kentaro and used this syntax

```
    SELECT Cast(badgenum As Int) As badgenum, Cast(lastunlockdate as datetime) As lastunlockdate,
       Cast(Today As datetime) as currentDate
FROM OPENQUERY(postgrez, 
                 'Select 
                  badgenumber As "badgenum"
                  ,lastunlockdate As "Last Unlock"
                  ,currentDate As "Today"
                  From doorswipesystem')
```

but I got a compile error of:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I verified field types in my postgres database as well and they are int & date.  The only thing that I can think of that could be causing the issue is NULL dates for the two date fields?

Comment: quick and dirty way is to use CAST or CONVERT in the SELECT statement. SELECT CAST(badgenum AS INT), CAST([Last Unlock] AS DATE), CAST([Today] AS DATE) FROM OPENQUERY(.....  Note that I omitted aliases.

Comment: @Kentaro - see my edit.

Comment: From your edit, it looks like you are doing `Cast(currentDate As datetime)` when the name of the field that you should be trying to cast is `[Today]`.

Comment: @JNevill - good catch, but same error.

Comment: use CONVERT instead of CAST. I suspect the input date format is different from that of SQL server, e.g. mmddyyyy vs ddmmyyyy. Use CONVERT twice if you need to. first to convert it from varchar to date, 2nd to convert to the style you use.